# Trying to understand #selector and what happens with its method requires arguments Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I understand that the #selector(myFunc) only "points" to myFunc.  Let's say I have

```
UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
```

and

```
func handleLogout(shouldAnimate: Bool) {
    present(someController, animated: shouldAnimate, completion: nil)
}
```

What happens to the parameter shouldAnimate when the bar button item is pressed?

Sometimes I want to animate the view, sometimes I don't.  It depends on whether handleLogout is is called from the button or not.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

I have looked at many other threads and they all say to use instance variables but I don't understand how that would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case parameter will always be the sender which is the instance of `UIBarButtonItem`. So you should change the method signature like this..

```
func handleLogout(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //let shouldAnimate = decide what you want here... 
    present(someController, animated: shouldAnimate, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I would upvote but I have less than 15 rep... that clarifies things thank you

Comment: @SanzioAngeli u can mark it as answer to your question